# Multiple gravity "zones" in a world

Tags: box2d

I have a world that I want to divide in two like this:

```
 ____________________
|                    |
|                    | 
|        A           |
|                    |
|                    |
|____________________|
|                    |
|                    | 
|        B           |
|                    |
|                    |
|____________________|
```

And I want the gravity in A to go up and in B to go down.

How can I implement a world like this using Box2D?

Comment: To answer your closed question... Yes, it is possible... If you were hoping for a more detailed question, I suggest editing your post to include more information :)

Comment: Did you try this already? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create static bodies A and B, each of them with rectangular fixtures with [`b2Fixture::setSensor(true)`](http://arme-mod.googlecode.com/hg-history/9d4908fceb62955903e08b586ff8fdf09ce10107/arm.mod/box2d.mod/Documentation/html/classb2_fixture.html#a6198a81dcee0fe814d730383ebfa7038).

Utilize the [`b2ContactListener::BeginContact`](http://arme-mod.googlecode.com/hg-history/9d4908fceb62955903e08b586ff8fdf09ce10107/arm.mod/box2d.mod/Documentation/html/classb2_contact_listener.html#a35148fc56fb9eac12077200fbd928f65) and [`b2ContactListener::EndContact`](http://arme-mod.googlecode.com/hg-history/9d4908fceb62955903e08b586ff8fdf09ce10107/arm.mod/box2d.mod/Documentation/html/classb2_contact_listener.html#a35148fc56fb9eac12077200fbd928f65) to determine when a body is entering or leaving areas A or B. When one of these events is detected, modify the [`gravityScale`](http://arme-mod.googlecode.com/hg-history/9d4908fceb62955903e08b586ff8fdf09ce10107/arm.mod/box2d.mod/Documentation/html/classb2_body.html#a8e66a570c2aeee93b29d84cae861a612) of the dynamic body accordingly. In pseudocode these functions should look like this:

```
function BeginContact(contact){
    /* Do some preliminary tests to determine this is a collision between
    a sensor and dynamic body, and store them in local vars staticBod and dynamicBod*/
    //Assume the gravity exerted by each sensor body is stored in the userdata
    dynamicBod.SetGravityScale(dynamicBod.GetGravityScale() + static_cast<float>(staticBod.GetUserData()));
}
```

The `EndContact` function should just undo that:

```
function EndContact(contact){
    /* Do some preliminary tests to determine this is a collision between
    a sensor and dynamic body, and store them in local vars staticBod and dynamicBod*/
    dynamicBod.SetGravityScale(dynamicBod.GetGravityScale() - static_cast<float>(staticBod.GetUserData()));
}
```

You also need to call [`b2World::SetGravity`](http://arme-mod.googlecode.com/hg-history/9d4908fceb62955903e08b586ff8fdf09ce10107/arm.mod/box2d.mod/Documentation/html/classb2_world.html#aeafa43d6580e1dddb0675e672ca2375c) to some reasonable vector (e.g. (0,-1))

Comment: I see, so you don't apply a "global" gravity anymore but a specific one on each dynamic object, brilliant!